# Terminal commands not working

Tags: linux, shell-script, terminal, linux-kernel, mv

I moved all files starting with lib from /../ to some folder as,
`mv /../lib* /to/some/folder`

after which I can't move it back.It comes as 
`-bash: /bin/mv: /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2: bad ELF interpreter: No such file or directory`

Even for `ls` it comes as `-bash: /bin/ls: /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2: bad ELF interpreter: No such file or directory`

Comment: What is ”some folder”?

Comment: my home folder which i did'nt want to mention

Comment: If you like to be able to ever fix this without a helper boot medium, you need to know exactly what you did and if you like to get help on that, you need to share this information.

Comment: Is busybox installed on your system?

Comment: the thing is I moved the files starting with `lib*` to some other location, after which I couldn't move it back as `mv` was not working.

Comment: yes busybox is installed

Comment: Can you start busybox from the shell?

Comment: how do I do that?

Comment: If yes, you can try `busybox mv /to/some/folder/lib* /`. This would then move the files back. But to give you the correct command, you should write the EXACT command how you moved the files in the first place

Comment: Can you use utilities like `ls` again? Maybe start a new shell

Comment: Yeah I can use it. Everything works fine now. Thanks to you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The restauration using `busybox` worked in your case as you had `busybox` installed.

`busybox` is a statically linked binary and this helped in your case, but there is no need to use statically linked binaries to repair this kind of defects.

You could do this as well:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/some/path/where/the/libs/are mv ....
```

If you moved the dymamic runtime linker as well, you also need to manually call the runtime linker as well. To understand how this works, call:

```
man ld.so.1
```

or on Linux

```
man ld.so
```

This typically results in a command line like:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/libs /path/to/libs/ld.so.1  mv ....
```

On Linux replace `/path/to/libs/ld.so.1` by `/path/to/libs/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` or what is actually used on your system.

In general, you need to know whether the binary you like to call is a 32 bit or a 64 bit binary and to call the right dynamic runtime linker.

BTW: This is the method that is documented for Solaris since 2004 and since that year, there are no statically linked binaries on Solaris anymore.